# syslog.1 and deamon.log.1 files grow to 2 giga each

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I'm running raspbian jessie on raspberrypi, with an eight giga SD card.

This message is written again and again hundred times in a second and catching all the place on my SD card.

```
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stop job pending for unit, delaying automatic restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: autologin@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stop job pending for unit, delaying automatic restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: autologin@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stop job pending for unit, delaying automatic restart.
```

This is the log of what is happening before that

```
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed)...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Prepare console...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi raspi-config[278]: Checking if shift key is held down:Error opening '/dev/input/event*': No such file or directory
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi raspi-config[278]: No. Switching to ondemand scaling governor.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed).
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi kbd[279]: Setting console screen modes.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi kbd[279]: setterm: $TERM is not defined.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Prepare console.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set console font and keymap...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi console-setup[326]: Setting up console font and keymap...done.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set console font and keymap.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 253 (plymouthd).
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi networking[275]: Configuring network interfaces...done.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Raise network interfaces..
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting ifup for wlan0...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started ifup for wlan0.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting System Initialization.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Sockets.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Timers.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Manage Sound Card State (restore and store).
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Restore Sound Card State...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Basic System.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down....
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Regular background program processing daemon...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Autogenerate and use a swap file...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: triggerhappy hotkey daemon...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[427]: version 6.7.1 starting
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[427]: dev: loaded udev
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[427]: eth0: adding address fe80::69e:994b:b61c:4ba7
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[427]: wlan0: adding address fe80::a4a4:10d:6a57:4f8d
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[427]: forked to background, child pid 449
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 105) and group 'avahi' (GID 110).
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[443]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[493]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Successfully called chroot().
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Loading service file /services/udisks.service.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::a4a4:10d:6a57:4f8d.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for fe80::a4a4:10d:6a57:4f8d on wlan0.*.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering HINFO record with values 'ARMV7L'/'LINUX'.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Restore Sound Card State.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down..
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Network.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Network is Online.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start xrdp and sesman daemons...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start NTP daemon...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Permit User Sessions...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Permit User Sessions.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::69e:994b:b61c:4ba7.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for fe80::69e:994b:b61c:4ba7 on eth0.*.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[437]: Starting dphys-swapfile swapfile setup ...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi triggerhappy[438]: Error opening '/dev/input/event*': No such file or directory
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: triggerhappy hotkey daemon.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 253 (plymouthd).
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntp[526]: Starting NTP server: ntpderror: unexpectedly disconnected from boot status daemon
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Getty on tty1...
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[437]: want /var/swap=100MByte, checking existing: keeping it
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[637]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Jul 25 22:35:28 UTC 2016 (1)
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: proto: precision = 0.520 usec
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Listen normally on 3 lo ::1 UDP 123
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: peers refreshed
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Listening on routing socket on fd #20 for interface updates
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Login Prompts.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start NTP daemon.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntp[526]: .
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Deferring DNS for 0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Deferring DNS for 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 1
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Deferring DNS for 2.debian.pool.ntp.org 1
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Deferring DNS for 3.debian.pool.ntp.org 1
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi ntpd[651]: signal_no_reset: signal 17 had flags 4000000
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Autogenerate and use a swap file.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi dphys-swapfile[437]: done.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi xrdp[525]: Starting Remote Desktop Protocol server : xrdp sesman.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start xrdp and sesman daemons.
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi lightdm[556]: ** (lightdm:556): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
Jul 28 00:04:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Jul 28 00:04:31 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Server startup complete. Host name is raspberrypi.local. Local service cookie is 183500800.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Service "raspberrypi" (/services/udisks.service) successfully established.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi lightdm[556]: ** (process:668): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting user-1000.slice.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Created slice user-1000.slice.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Session c1 of user pi.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Session c1 of user pi.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Starting Paths.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Reached target Paths.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Starting Timers.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Reached target Timers.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Starting Sockets.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Reached target Sockets.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Starting Basic System.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Reached target Basic System.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Starting Default.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Reached target Default.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Startup finished in 37ms.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: host name not found: 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: host name not found: 1.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: host name not found: 2.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jul 28 00:04:32 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: host name not found: 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jul 28 00:04:33 raspberrypi dbus[442]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkitd.service'
Jul 28 00:04:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi hciattach[428]: bcm43xx_init
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi hciattach[428]: Flash firmware /lib/firmware/BCM43430A1.hcd
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi hciattach[428]: Set Controller UART speed to 921600 bit/s
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi hciattach[428]: Device setup complete
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Multi-User System.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Graphical Interface.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi polkitd[748]: started daemon version 0.105 using authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi dbus[442]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill1...
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill1.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: Bluetooth daemon 5.23
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Startup finished in 2.025s (kernel) + 8.055s (userspace) = 10.080s.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: Starting SDP server
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi dbus[442]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service'
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi dbus[442]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 initialized
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi dbus[442]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1'
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[794]: Successfully called chroot.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[794]: Successfully dropped privileges.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[794]: Successfully limited resources.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[794]: Running.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[794]: Watchdog thread running.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[794]: Canary thread running.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd-hostnamed[798]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi dbus[442]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi dbus[442]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' unit='udisks2.service'
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Session c2 of user pi.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user pi.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[794]: Successfully made thread 790 of process 790 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[794]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi udisksd[816]: udisks daemon version 2.1.3 starting
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi dbus[442]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi udisksd[816]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.15 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jul 28 00:04:34 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.15 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jul 28 00:04:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jul 28 00:04:36 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.15 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jul 28 00:04:36 raspberrypi bluetoothd[776]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.15 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jul 28 00:04:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jul 28 00:04:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jul 28 00:04:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 28 00:04:40 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[1044]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/mtp-probe' 'mtp-probe /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 1 5': No such file or directory
Jul 28 00:04:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting system-usb_modeswitch.slice.
Jul 28 00:04:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /system.slice: Invalid argument
Jul 28 00:04:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Created slice system-usb_modeswitch.slice.
Jul 28 00:04:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch...
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[1100]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/mtp-probe' 'mtp-probe /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 1 6': No such file or directory
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: adding address fe80::584f:751f:bb3e:e26b
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: waiting for carrier
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: carrier acquired
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: DUID 00:01:00:01:1f:77:66:46:b8:27:eb:93:e6:27
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: IAID 8f:27:9a:64
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: carrier lost
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: deleting address fe80::584f:751f:bb3e:e26b
Jul 28 00:04:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started USB_ModeSwitch.
Jul 28 00:04:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: carrier acquired
Jul 28 00:04:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: adding address fe80::584f:751f:bb3e:e26b
Jul 28 00:04:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: IAID 8f:27:9a:64
Jul 28 00:04:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jul 28 00:04:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: rebinding lease of 192.168.8.100
Jul 28 00:04:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: NAK: from 192.168.8.1
Jul 28 00:04:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jul 28 00:04:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv6 with address fe80::584f:751f:bb3e:e26b.
Jul 28 00:04:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 28 00:04:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for fe80::584f:751f:bb3e:e26b on eth1.*.
Jul 28 00:04:52 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Listen normally on 4 eth1 fe80::584f:751f:bb3e:e26b UDP 123
Jul 28 00:04:52 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: peers refreshed
Jul 28 00:04:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: offered 192.168.8.100 from 192.168.8.1
Jul 28 00:04:54 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: host name not found: 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jul 28 00:04:54 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: host name not found: 1.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jul 28 00:04:54 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: host name not found: 2.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jul 28 00:04:54 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: host name not found: 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jul 28 00:04:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: leased 192.168.8.100 for 86400 seconds
Jul 28 00:04:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 192.168.8.100.
Jul 28 00:04:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: adding route to 192.168.8.0/24
Jul 28 00:04:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 28 00:04:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: adding default route via 192.168.8.1
Jul 28 00:04:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[440]: Registering new address record for 192.168.8.100 on eth1.IPv4.
Jul 28 00:04:59 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: Listen normally on 5 eth1 192.168.8.100 UDP 123
Jul 28 00:04:59 raspberrypi ntpd[647]: peers refreshed
Jul 28 00:05:01 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: DNS 0.debian.pool.ntp.org -> 109.226.40.40
Jul 28 00:05:01 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: DNS 1.debian.pool.ntp.org -> 109.226.40.40
Jul 28 00:05:01 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: DNS 2.debian.pool.ntp.org -> 109.226.40.40
Jul 28 00:05:01 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[651]: DNS 3.debian.pool.ntp.org -> 109.226.40.40
Jul 28 00:05:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[449]: eth1: no IPv6 Routers available
Jul 28 00:05:19 raspberrypi systemd[676]: Time has been changed
Jul 28 00:05:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Jul 28 00:20:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Jul 28 00:20:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: autologin@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stop job pending for unit, delaying automatic restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: autologin@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stop job pending for unit, delaying automatic restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: autologin@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stop job pending for unit, delaying automatic restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: autologin@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Jul 29 00:04:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stop job pending for unit, delaying automatic restart.
```

I Searched everywhere but found nothing.
I could command the OS to stop writing the log but i don't want that.

I want to understand what the log line means, why it is written over and over again and really solve the problem.

Comment: Has this always happened?  Have you just changed a setting or added new hardware?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Joan. My systems use to have USB connected to them and that happened when no USB was connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This messages are from `autologin@tty1.service` that means you have **autologin** enabled. If you look at the unit with `systemctl cat autologin@tty1.service` you will find the lines:

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
```

That means if the *autologin* stops it will restart immediately, also if it fails. It seems your *autologin* on **tty1** always fails and fill up your logs by attempts to restart it.

At first you should disable *autlogin* on **tty1** and then look why it fails.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I have just solved the problem thanks to your advise.